# WordProcessingDocument with MemoryStream gives corrupt results

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I'm attempting to use OpenXML for opening a word document, and after modifications, return a modified version to the user as a downloadable file. As for the downloadable portion of this, I have that covered, in that, I modify my response to simply return a word document. But, what I am having a problem with is successfully opening and modifying a word document. While I am able to provide a document to download, the file is consistently "corrupt" when I open it.

I have an extremely simple snippet that is still returning a corrupt word document. It's almost as though the file becomes corrupt the very moment I open it (since I've removed all of the modifications from this snippet).

```
Private Function GenerateExportWithTemplate() As MemoryStream

  Dim template As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strTemplateFileName)

  Using ms As New MemoryStream()
    ms.Write(template, 0, template.Length)

    Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, True)

      'Code to modify word document.

    End Using

    Return ms
  End Using
End Function
```

I don't believe I fully understand what is happening in the snippet above. Any explanation in why I am receiving a corrupt file would be greatly appreciated.

How do I successfully open and modify a WordProcessingDocument from a template file, and return as a memory stream? While there are a million examples of how to open a file and make modifications, I have yet to find one that is successful. Meaning, the file is corrupt every time. How do I do this without receiving a corrupt word document as the result?

Comment: post your full code from the 'Code to modify word document.
area and we can better help you.

Comment: With the current code, where the comment is just a placeholder for where I would put code, I still receive a corrupted file. I use this code to open the file into a memory stream, and then return the memory stream as a byte array in the response. The code you see above is producing a corrupted word document.

Comment: will you accept c#?

Comment: @Taterhead Absolutely!